# How to retrieve the active network location on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I want to fetch the active network location on a Windows machine (i.e. home (private)/work/public).

Is there any API present to fetch this information?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's an API for that. The one you're looking for is a COM interface, [`INetwork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370750.aspx). It has a method named [`GetCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370780.aspx) that returns a value from the [`NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370800.aspx):

```
NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC               = 0x00  // a public network
NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PRIVATE              = 0x01  // a private network
NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_DOMAIN_AUTHENTICATED = 0x02  // an Active Directory domain
```

Naturally, this API only exists in Windows Vista and later, where the network location feature was first introduced.

And it's also worth pointing out that the usefulness of the information it returns is, in my opinion, rather limited. You can't make any kind of assumptions about the settings for a particular network based on its type, since the user can modify those settings. To obtain accurate values, you will need to query the actual settings you need to know (e.g. the status of particular firewall ports).

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. We can get category as public/private. I have even tried the get_CurrentProfileTypes API of INetFwPolicy2 interface. I want to fetch whether network location is Home/Work/Public. According to my observation Home & Work are considered in private type. Can we get home or work separately and not under private network.